# Show this function $K(m/n)$ is onto

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have seen multiple questions about proving that a function over rationale numbers is one-to-one correspondence. I just want to discuss my issue with the onto part.

**Onto part**:

Given that $K(\frac{m}{n})$, $K: \mathbb{Q}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined from set of positive rational numbers to the set positive integers is defined as follows,

$$K(\frac{m}{n}) = p_1^{2a_1}\cdots p_s^{2a_s}q_1^{2b_1-1}\cdots q_t^{2b_t-1}$$

**Note**: $2k$ is odd power and $2k-1$ is even power.

where $gcd(m,n)=1$ and the prime-power factorization of $m$ and $n$ are

$$m = p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_s^{a_s}, n = q_1^{b_1}\cdots q_t^{b_t}$$

To show that a function is onto, we have to show that $\exists \frac{g}{h} s.t. K(\frac{g}{h})=y$, s.t. $y \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let the prime factorization of $y$ be $r_1^{y_1}\cdots r_n^{y_n}$ and let us define the following,

$$g = \prod_{i\in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}, y_i~even}r_i^{\frac{y_i}{2}}$$
$$h = \prod_{i\in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}, y_j~odd}r_i^{\frac{(y_j+1)}{2}}$$

**Question**: can you please explain how $gcd(g,h)=1$ based on above information? Second, can you show how $K(\frac{g}{h})=y$? How we can guarantee that primes of $g$ and $h$ are unique?

Comment: HInt: try an example to see how the notation works: e.g., take $y = 2^5\cdot3^4\cdot7^3\cdot11^4$.

Comment: Hint: can a prime factor $r_i$ belong both on $g$ and $h$?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis. Thank you. If $g=6, h=9$, then yes $r_i$ belongs to both?

Comment: @RobArthan. Thank you. so $h=2^5\times 7^3$ as it groups odd powers and $g=3^4\times 11^4$ as it groups even powers, so we have a value in the domain for $y$, this it's onto? What if the values we have are $2^5 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 7^3 \cdot 2^4 \cdot 11^4$? In that case, $2^4$ will be in $g$ while $2^5$ will be in $h$ , so $gcd(g,h) \ne 1$, is not it?

Comment: @Avra Look more carefully at the primes that you include in $g$ and $h$. Every $r_i$ will be raised in an either even or odd power in the factorization of $y$ but not both.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis. I am still unable to show that $gcd(g,h)=1$, can you please show me how to do only this part?

Comment: @Avra Let's take an example as I think it will clear up your confusion. Let's say $y=2^7 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 11^8 \cdot 13^1$. Now $r_1 = 2, r_2 = 3, r_3=11, r_4=13$ and $y_1 = 7, y_2 = 4, y_3 = 8, y_4 = 1$. The $y_i$'s that are even are $y_2$ and $y_4$. So $g$ will only contain $r_2=3$ and $r_3=11$ in it's prime decomposition. Similarly, $h$ will only contain $r_1=2$ and $r_4=13$ in it's prime decomposition. Now $g$ and $h$ are coprime since they don't share a common prime factor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122551/discussion-between-avra-and-giorgos-giapitzakis).

Comment: $2^5 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 7^3 \cdot 2^4 \cdot 11^4$ is not what is meant by a prime factorisation here, because you've used the prime factor $2$ twice in the list of $r_i$s. In saying that $r_1^{y_1}\cdots r_n^{y_n}$ is the prime factorisation of a number, it is implicit that the $r_i$ are pairwise distinct.